# VBA to match a line in one sheet based on a few criteria and move antire row to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I would like to create a tool that helps me to do some manual tasks.

So, background:

I work at one of many finance companies and we receive couple thousand trades daily and we have to match it - it is automated - the system receives the trade from outside (called HE side) and compares details with our database (Called ME side) and if the details the same it will match it. But a few hundred HE side trades get stuck in the system. And it is my job to clear the backlog manually.

To do that I have to download HE side and ME side separately (.xls files) and compare in excel.

I have tried a few VBA, but I could not do fully functioning tool.

---

I will download both files and paste it into one:

Sheet1 contains HE side trades, sheet2 " contains ME side trades.
I want to make a tool that run through both sheets and based on matching criteria moves the row from A to Q to 3rd sheet. (from both sheet1 and sheet2)
Problem is both trades are inverted:

[image: me and his sides]

Matching criteria is: sheet1 Columns I,J,M should match I,J,M on sheet2 respectively.
And sheet1 column L should match sheet2 column O and vice versa (I have put colors above)

Based on this it should move matching rows from sheet1 and sheet2(A : Q) to sheet3
end product should look like this
[image: after matching and moving to sheet3]

Sheet1 and sheet2 contains data from A : AU but I only need to move A:Q
Both sheets have a few hundred rows.
And it should 1st matching rows 1st (if in sheet1 row 15 matches to sheet2 row 102 - it should move row 15 first and paste row 102 under it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's great that you're thinking at automating your mundane tasks, but it would be even better if you give it a go yourself first, there are countless VBA tutorials around.

The below assumes you have the spreadsheets separated, and the results in a third spreadsheet (where this code would reside).

Anyways, see if this gives you a starting point at least:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub findMatches()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'this workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet: Set wsDestination = wb.Sheets("your destination sheet name here")
    
    'get HIS workbook
    Dim wbHIS As Workbook: Set wbHIS = Workbooks.Open("C:\...yourpath...\wbHIS.xls")
    Dim wsHIS As Worksheet: Set wsHIS = wbHIS.Sheets("his sheet name here")
    
    'get ME workbook
    Dim wbME As Workbook: Set wbME = Workbooks.Open("C:\...yourpath...\wbME.xls")
    Dim wsME As Worksheet: Set wsME = wbME.Sheets("me sheet name here")
    
    'other variables
    Dim arrHis, arrME, arrDestination
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, x As Long, z As Long
    
    'get the data from the worksheets
    arrHis = getData(wsHIS)
    arrME = getData(wsME)
    
    If IsEmpty(arrHis) Or IsEmpty(arrME) Then GoTo exitSub
    
    'create the destination array with the max possible rows in case there is a match for every single row, assume same number of columns
    ReDim arrDestination(1 To UBound(arrHis, 1) + UBound(arrME, 1), 1 To UBound(arrME, 2))
    
    'iterate through all rows in his data
    x = 2
    For i = LBound(arrHis, 1) + 1 To UBound(arrHis, 1)
        'iterate through all rows in me data
        For j = LBound(arrME, 1) + 1 To UBound(arrME, 1)
            'if they match on columns "I", "J", "M"
            If arrHis(i, 9) = arrME(j, 9) _
                And arrHis(i, 10) = arrME(j, 10) _
                And arrHis(i, 13) = arrME(j, 13) Then
                
                'we add to the temp array
                For z = LBound(arrDestination, 2) To UBound(arrDestination, 2)
                    If x = 2 Then
                        'add headers
                        arrDestination(1, z) = arrHis(1, z)
                    End If
                    arrDestination(x, z) = arrHis(i, z)
                    arrDestination(x + 1, z) = arrME(j, z)
                Next z
                x = x + 2
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    'now dump the data back to the worksheet
    With wsDestination
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(x - 1, UBound(arrDestination, 2))) = arrDestination
    End With

exitSub:
    'close the workbooks
    wbHIS.Close
    wbME.Close
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Function getData(sht As Worksheet)
    With sht
        'allocate the data from the sheet to an array
        getData = .Range( _
            .Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, _
            .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column) _
        )
    End With
End Function
```

There is very little error handling here, I leave that to you.